# update latest columns based on another column in r

Tags: r, tidyverse

Let's say I have a big dataframe, and now I would like to update one column based on another column

I did ask this similar question before, but here I rechanged the format and combined all the situation into one dataframe, and I think it is worth to solve it.

I would like to update column `name3` based on `name2`, and keep two other columns.
My example as below

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c("BF1","BF3", "BF4", "BF3","BF3","BF1", "BF1", "BF1", "BF2", "BF2", "BF3"),
                 value = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11),
                 name2 = c("Hydnocarpus sumatranus (Miq.) Koord. var. sumatranus", "Hydnocarpus sumatranus (Miq.) Koord. var. sumatranus", 
                           "Hydnocarpus sumatranus (Miq.) Koord. var. sumatranus", "Hydnocarpus sumatranus (Miq.) Koord. var. sumatranus", 
                           "Senegalia rugata (Lam.) Britton & Rose", "Acacia pinnata", "Acacia pinnata", "Acer laurinum", "Acer laurinum Hassk.", "Acmella paniculata", "Acmella paniculata"),
                 name3 = c("Hydnocarpus sumatrana", "Hydnocarpus sumatrana", "Hydnocarpus sumatrana", "Hydnocarpus sumatranus (Miq.) Koord.","Acacia pinnata", "Acacia pinnata", 
                           "Acacia pinnata", "Acer laurinum", "Acer laurinum Hassk.", "Acmella paniculata", "Acmella paniculata"))

df

    ID value                                                name2                                name3
1  BF1     1 Hydnocarpus sumatranus (Miq.) Koord. var. sumatranus                Hydnocarpus sumatrana
2  BF3     2 Hydnocarpus sumatranus (Miq.) Koord. var. sumatranus                Hydnocarpus sumatrana
3  BF4     3 Hydnocarpus sumatranus (Miq.) Koord. var. sumatranus                Hydnocarpus sumatrana
4  BF3     4 Hydnocarpus sumatranus (Miq.) Koord. var. sumatranus Hydnocarpus sumatranus (Miq.) Koord.
5  BF3     5               Senegalia rugata (Lam.) Britton & Rose                       Acacia pinnata
6  BF1     6                                       Acacia pinnata                       Acacia pinnata
7  BF1     7                                       Acacia pinnata                       Acacia pinnata
8  BF1     8                                        Acer laurinum                        Acer laurinum
9  BF2     9                                 Acer laurinum Hassk.                 Acer laurinum Hassk.
10 BF2    10                                   Acmella paniculata                   Acmella paniculata
11 BF3    11                                   Acmella paniculata                   Acmella paniculata
```

Firstly, I would like to update `Acacia pinnata` by `Senegalia rugata (Lam.) Britton & Rose` with the condition as if the character of `name2` match with `name3` (i.e. `Acacia pinnata`), and simutaneously, the that of `name3` is on the same row with the other character of `name2` (i.e. `Senegalia rugata (Lam.) Britton & Rose` - name2 and `Acacia pinnata` - name3.

Secondly, I would like to replace `Acer laurinum` by `Acer laurinum Hassk.` saying that if two their first strings are similar, go get the longer one. Is that possible if we use with `str_detect`

Finally, my desired table looks like this

```
    ID value                                                name2                                name3
1  BF1     1 Hydnocarpus sumatranus (Miq.) Koord. var. sumatranus                Hydnocarpus sumatranus (Miq.) Koord. var. sumatranus
2  BF3     2 Hydnocarpus sumatranus (Miq.) Koord. var. sumatranus                Hydnocarpus sumatranus (Miq.) Koord. var. sumatranus
3  BF4     3 Hydnocarpus sumatranus (Miq.) Koord. var. sumatranus                Hydnocarpus sumatranus (Miq.) Koord. var. sumatranus
4  BF3     4 Hydnocarpus sumatranus (Miq.) Koord. var. sumatranus Hydnocarpus sumatranus (Miq.) Koord. var. sumatranus
5  BF3     5               Senegalia rugata (Lam.) Britton & Rose                       Senegalia rugata (Lam.) Britton & Rose
6  BF1     6                                       Acacia pinnata                       Senegalia rugata (Lam.) Britton & Rose
7  BF1     7                                       Acacia pinnata                       Senegalia rugata (Lam.) Britton & Rose
8  BF1     8                                        Acer laurinum                        Acer laurinum Hassk.
9  BF2     9                                 Acer laurinum Hassk.                 Acer laurinum Hassk.
10 BF2    10                                   Acmella paniculata                   Acmella paniculata
11 BF3    11                                   Acmella paniculata                   Acmella paniculata
```

Any suggestions for me, please?

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you wanted? If not, please let me know.

```
df %>%
  rowwise %>%
  mutate(name3 = case_when(
    name3 == 'Acacia pinnata' & name2 %in% c("Senegalia rugata (Lam.) Britton & Rose", "Acacia pinnata") ~ "Senegalia rugata (Lam.) Britton & Rose",
    str_detect(name3, "Acer laurinum") ~ "Acer laurinum Hassk.",
    TRUE ~ name3
    ))

   ID    value name2                                                name3                                 
   <chr> <dbl> <chr>                                                <chr>                                 
 1 BF1       1 Hydnocarpus sumatranus (Miq.) Koord. var. sumatranus Hydnocarpus sumatrana                 
 2 BF3       2 Hydnocarpus sumatranus (Miq.) Koord. var. sumatranus Hydnocarpus sumatrana                 
 3 BF4       3 Hydnocarpus sumatranus (Miq.) Koord. var. sumatranus Hydnocarpus sumatrana                 
 4 BF3       4 Hydnocarpus sumatranus (Miq.) Koord. var. sumatranus Hydnocarpus sumatranus (Miq.) Koord.  
 5 BF3       5 Senegalia rugata (Lam.) Britton & Rose               Senegalia rugata (Lam.) Britton & Rose
 6 BF1       6 Acacia pinnata                                       Senegalia rugata (Lam.) Britton & Rose
 7 BF1       7 Acacia pinnata                                       Senegalia rugata (Lam.) Britton & Rose
 8 BF1       8 Acer laurinum                                        Acer laurinum Hassk.                  
 9 BF2       9 Acer laurinum Hassk.                                 Acer laurinum Hassk.                  
10 BF2      10 Acmella paniculata                                   Acmella paniculata                    
11 BF3      11 Acmella paniculata                                   Acmella paniculata
```

Comment: thank you. i mean i worked this example, but since I have so many cases like that, then we can not call them directly right? instead i am trying to wrap them by using columns as my condition

Comment: @Anh I'm sorry for misunderstanding. Then for a second condition, if `name3` conatains `name2`, there do exists some match of this kind of containing(like `Acer laurinum`, `... Hassk.`). Do you want to apply for every match?

Comment: for the second condition, it seems to be `name3` are exact the same as `name2` (as you can see), so, i was thinking like 1. we can say like you said `name3` contains `name2` in which some matchs would be found (i.e. `Acer laurinum`), then we will take the author part behind. 2. Instead of using `name2`, we can use only `name3` and say that if 2 characters having the same two first strings then take the longer. But I am thinking now taking a longer name would raise issuse. What do you think?

Comment: @Anh What's confusing is that in row 8, both `name2` and `name3` are `Acer laurinum` but you want `name3` become `Acer laurinum Hassk.`. That's why I asked that for any matched pairs, not only in row, in whole data in `name2` and `name3` needed to be choose longer one, if `name3` contains `name2`.

Comment: Yes, I think I gonna make another question, since I already changed another format from that (hope it will be clear now)